# Moving image through screen react native

Tags: reactjs, native

I have an splashpage that leads to a loginpage. The splashpage is only visible for 1000ms and it has an image in the center of the screen, i want this image to move during the 1000ms to the top so where the loginpage comes in the image is in the top and the login information appears in the center. 
Any idea how could i do that? 
Thanks.

Comment: By looking at this library you can translate your view in any position, you can also create your own animation component for this: https://github.com/ldn0x7dc/react-native-view-transformer

Comment: Can you do a little example of this?, i saw that this component has no example for the animation part and i dont manage to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: you can customize your component by implementing as your choice navigation style from here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html

Comment: but this component only works for the whole view, i mean, if i only want to move the image and not the whole view is it possible?

Comment: yes you could wrap your image with that component.